# How to convert MediaFile Object to File Object?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, media, record

I am developing a Real Time ionic app. To capture audio/images I am working with cordova plugin media capture. I would be able to send through api post multipart-form-data the file object MediaFile (mediaFile).I need to convert MediaFile Object JS to File Object JS (Api multipart post only accept File, not MediaFile)

```
$scope.captureImage = function() {
      navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccessImage,captureErrorImage);
}

function captureSuccessImage(mediaFiles) {

  var i, mediaFile, len;

  for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {

      mediaFile = mediaFiles[i];


  }

}
```

Comment: Are you want to file url to data_uri

Answer (score 1):

it will Support media path also. I am using this file transfer code. please have a look.

```
 postFile(imageData, id) {
let base64Image = imageData;
this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imageData)
  .then(filePath => base64Image)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
console.log(base64Image);
const fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();
let imageName = base64Image;
var options: FileUploadOptions = {
  fileKey: "file",
  fileName: imageName.substr(imageName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
  mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
  chunkedMode: false,
  params: { 'id': id },
  headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token"),  'Connection': "close" }
}
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fileTransfer.upload(imageName, encodeURI(this.MainURL + "/UploadMedia"), options)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      resolve(200);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);

      reject(500);
    })
})


}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I really needed to convert MediaFile to File in order to make vimeo API work.
Since MediaFile is a File:

```
  for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {

      mediaFile = mediaFiles[i];

      var file = new File(mediaFile.name, mediaFile.localURL, mediaFile.type, 
                          mediaFile.lastModifiedDate, mediaFile.size);
  }
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: It worked that way... Are you with another problem?